# How can I customize what notifications show up on my notifications bar (RAZR MAXX running ICS)?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications, customization, motorola-droid-razr

I want to customize what I see in the notifications bar/shade. (eg. I don't want notifications for facebook messages, I don't want to see my weather app in the notification bar).

I looked in the apps' setup areas, but didn't see any way to change this, specifically for the weather channel app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ICS, it's up to the application. You will have to check the settings for each individual app and see if they allow you to control what shows up in your Notification bar. Unfortunately, there is no way to control this through Android itself...

However, note that in Jelly Bean, the ability to monitor and control which apps display notifications is integrated into the app settings options. See below:

[image: Notification Control]